# Eager Garbage Collection in Java

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I would like to better understand my application and specifically its memory footprint.

I do understand the concepts of garbage-collection and I am aware, that there will always be a certain amount of dead objects in the heap, however, I would like to minimize this amount such that monitoring with JConsole (or JVisualVM) provides me with some information about the currently required (not occupied) space.

Is there any way to configure an existing garbage-collector (e.g. G1GC) in the SunVM such that (at the cost of responsiveness and runtime) the amount of dead objects in the heap is minimized?

**Clarification**

To be more clear about my objectives: My application is non-interactive so the memory-footprint over time is more or less the same between two runs. I want to determine the minimum required heap space and the influence, code changes have on that footprint. The output from JConsole is not really helping here because of the dead objects. I also want to know, whether my peak-memory really is an outstanding peak at one point in time or whether it is streched over time. This is why reducing the Xmx until I reach a OOME is not what gets me there.

Also: I'm talking about use during developer tests, not the use in production here. In production, througput and performance are - of course - more important than a more realistic memroy-footprint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to know the total amount of memory that your application is using you must monitor it for quite a long time. Samples of the heap at random moments of the application:

```
jps -> output the pid of java process
jmap -dump:live,format=b,file=heap.bin [pid]
```

and then with `jhat` navigate the heap. There are another tools to do so.

Doing this you will know what's on the heap at a moment.

Bear in mind that objects such as `memory mapped files` are not stored in the heap but in the memory.

When reaching `OOM` try adding this, and then reading the output to see which objects are actually in the heap:

```
-XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:HeapDumpPath=./java_pid<pid>.hprof
```

To do so, enable the `GC log` and then use a tool such as [GCViewer](https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer).

```
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
 -XX:+PrintGCDetails
-verbose:gc
-Xloggc:garbage_collector -> this set the file of the output
```

When you talk about heap, I understand that you are talking about the `tenured` space. If so, you need to know the average life of objects. And follow some best practices and then do the fine tuning. Also remember that issuing a `System.gc()` does not guarantees that the `GC` is performed.

The thing is that instances goes to `young generation (eden)` and when  it is full a `minor GC` is performed. Objects that still reachable are passed to one of the two spaces called `survivor`. Once this is full that space is dumped into `tenured`. When full, a `full GC` executes and delete all instances that are not reachable.

One thing you can do is to use `primitives` in methods. Those won't be placed in the heap as their span of life is in the thread stack.

The useful parameters are those which tie the size of the `tenured and young generation (eden)`. These works by ratios. If you are to issue many `GC` bear in mind to set a max time for `GC stop`.

Some interesting parameters are:

```
-XX:MinFreeHeapRatio=  
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=  
-XX:NewRatio=
-XX:SurvivorRatio
```

For example, setting `-XX:NewRatio=3` means that the ratio between the young and old generation is 1:3; in other words, the combined size of eden and the survivor spaces will be one fourth of the heap.

Anyway I don't know why you need this requirement. I usually worry only about the `throughput` and only care for those parameters when the `throughput` is bad.

Comment: Is the term "ternured" or "tenured" (I don't know) - I have seen the latter

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I added a clarification to the question. I'm afraid tenured alone is not enough, I basically want to know the amount of living data at any time throughout the execution to determine minimum memory requirements and to asses what impact changes to the application have (wrt memory size)

Comment: So, your suggestion is to periodically dump the heap and analyze the amount of living objects? Wouldn't I get the same if I added a new thread to my application to call `System.gc` every - say - minute?

Comment: callings to System.gc() are not guarantee to trigger the GC. Also my suggestion is to add the verbose GC parameters that will give you an idea the how the heap is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `-Xgenconfig` flag when starting your Java application. You can read more about it [here](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/garbage/#2.6).

Quote from the website:

> The genconfig switch can be used to specify the heap sizes for the
>   young and old generations explicitly. It also allows an old-generation
>   collector to be specified. (The genconfig option makes the -Xms and
>   -Xmx options unnecessary, but if used with genconfig option -Xmx is still honored as a 
>   means to limit the old-generation heap size.)

By specifying smaller heap sizes, the GC get triggered more often. I believe this is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

While there certainly is a way to configure the GC subsystem to be more aggressive than the default, in all probabilty you'll realize that you are fighting against the tide trying to warp you code towards zero garbage. The standard Java library relies at practically every step on a fast gc-ing of short-lived objects. Examples are things as simple as string concatenation, enhanced for loop, autoboxing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but it depends on what your application is doing. You can only find this answer by experimenting and enabling the GC logs.

Using this, you will be able to find the minimal size of the old generation for your app, and then you can start experimenting different sizes for the young generation.

- A smaller young generation will mean more frequent collections but a smaller memory footprint
- A bigger your generation will mean less frequent collections, but a bigger memory footprint

Note that if the young generation is too small, objects may be prematurely promoted in the old generation without meeting the lifetime requirements for that. You can detect this when you see more full GC collections.

Comment: I'm not sure, how reading the GCLogs will help me. Within the logs, I get information about how much live data is in my heap at the time of collection (basically the low-peaks at the JConsole-memory-graph). What it doesn't tell me is the maximum amount of live-data during that execution, or am I wrong?

Comment: Considering that the GC collections are stop-the-world operations, it means that immediately after a collection, the only things left are live objects. So after each collection, you have the minimal amount of needed heap memory to store live objects. Now you can try different heap sizes in the range `[max_needed_memory_for_live_objects + 1; ...[`